# VBA Send email through Gmail

Tags: excel, vba, gmail

I have searched for ways to send emails automatically from an Excel spreadsheet. There are many solutions but none work for my company email -- it uses Gmail but with its own name, ei, employee@company.com. Thus, the Gmail SMTP do not work, and all the code around the web is useless for my objective.

I was wondering if there is a way to send instructions to prepare the email once I'm logged into my account without the need for sending it thought the SMTP. For instance, it would be very helpful if I could press a button and in Chrome initiate a new email, put in the To field the content of cell A1, in the Subject Field the content of cell B1, attach the file indicated in cell C1, etc.

Any suggestion would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: I can‘t provide an answer, but suggest to use additional tags for your question. There are some gmail-tags and you should carefully select appropriate ones.